# Why does my segue not wait until completion handler finished?

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have a page based app, using RootViewController, ModelViewController, DataViewController, and a SearchViewController.

In my searchViewController, I search for an item and then add or remove that Item to an array which is contained in a Manager class(and UserDefaults), which the modelViewController uses to instantiate an instance of DataViewController with the correct information loaded using the dataObject. Depending on whether an Item was added or removed, I use a Bool to determine which segue was used, addCoin or removeCoin, so that the RootViewController(PageView) will show either the last page in the array, (when a page is added) or the first (when removed).

Everything was working fine until I ran into an error which I can not diagnose, the problem is that when I add a page, the app crashes, giving me a "unexpectadely found nil when unwrapping an optional value"

This appears to be the problem function, in the searchViewController 'self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCoin"' seems to be called instantly, even without the dispatchque:

```
@objc func addButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

    print("Button tapped")

    if Manager.shared.coins.contains(dataObject) {
        Duplicate()
    } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 5 {
        max()
    } else {
        Manager.shared.addCoin(coin: dataObject)

        CGPrices.shared.getData(arr: true, completion: { (success) in
            print(Manager.shared.coins)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCoin", sender: self)
            }
        })

    }

    searchBar.text = ""
}
```

Meaning that In my DataViewController, this function will find nil:

```
func getIndex() {
    let index = CGPrices.shared.coinData.index(where: { $0.id == dataObject })!
    dataIndex = index
}
```

I can't find out why it does not wait for completion.

I also get this error about threads:

```
[Assert] Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
```

which is why I try to do the push segue using dispatch que

Here is my searchViewController full code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let selectionLabel = UILabel()
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    let addButton = UIButton()
    let removeButton = UIButton()

    var filteredObject: [String] = []
    var dataObject = ""

    var isSearching = false

    //Add Button Action.
    @objc func addButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        print("Button tapped")

        if Manager.shared.coins.contains(dataObject) {
            Duplicate()
        } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 5 {
            max()
        } else {
            Manager.shared.addCoin(coin: dataObject)

            CGPrices.shared.getData(arr: true, completion: { (success) in
                print(Manager.shared.coins)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCoin", sender: self)
                }
            })

        }

        searchBar.text = ""
    }

    //Remove button action.
    @objc func removeButtonActon(sender: UIButton!) {

        print("Button tapped")

        if Manager.shared.coins.contains(dataObject) {
            Duplicate()
        } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 5 {
            max()
        } else {
            Manager.shared.removeCoin(coin: dataObject)

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCoin", sender: self)
        }

        searchBar.text = ""
    }

    //Prepare for segue, pass removeCoinSegue Bool depending on remove or addCoin.
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "addCoin" {

            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? RootViewController {
                destinationVC.addCoinSegue = true
            }

        } else if segue.identifier == "addCoin" {

            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? RootViewController {
                destinationVC.addCoinSegue = false
            }
        }
    }

    //Remove button action.
    @objc func removeButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

        if Manager.shared.coins.count == 1 {
            removeAlert()
        } else {
            Manager.shared.removeCoin(coin: dataObject)

            print(Manager.shared.coins)
            print(dataObject)

            searchBar.text = ""
            self.removeButton.isHidden = true

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "removeCoin", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

    //Search/Filter the struct from CGNames, display both the Symbol and the Name but use the ID as dataObject.
    func filterStructForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            isSearching = true

            filteredObject = CGNames.shared.coinNameData.filter {

                // if you need to search key and value and include partial matches
                // $0.key.contains(searchText) || $0.value.contains(searchText)

                // if you need to search caseInsensitively key and value and include partial matches
                $0.name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil || $0.symbol.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
                }
                .map{ $0.id }

        } else {
            isSearching = false
            print("NoText")
        }
    }

    //Running filter function when text changes.
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filterStructForSearchText(searchText: searchText)

        if isSearching == true && filteredObject.count > 0 {

            addButton.isHidden = false
            dataObject = filteredObject[0]
            selectionLabel.text = dataObject

            if Manager.shared.coins.contains(dataObject) {
                removeButton.isHidden = false
                addButton.isHidden = true
            } else {
                removeButton.isHidden = true
                addButton.isHidden = false
            }

        } else {
            addButton.isHidden = true
            removeButton.isHidden = true
            selectionLabel.text = "e.g. btc/bitcoin"
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup the UI.
        self.view.backgroundColor = .gray
        setupView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    }

    //Hide keyboard
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //Alerts
    func removeAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Can't Remove", message: "\(dataObject) can't be deleted, add another to delete \(dataObject)", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func Duplicate() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Duplicate", message: "\(dataObject) is already in your pages!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func max() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Maximum Reached", message: "\(dataObject) can't be added, you have reached the maximum of 5 coins. Please delete a coin to add another.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and here is the DataViewController

```
import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!

    //Variables and Objects.

    //The dataObject carries the chosen cryptocurrencies ID from the CoinGecko API to use to get the correct data to load on each object.
    var dataObject = String()

    //The DefaultCurrency (gbp, eur...) chosen by the user.
    var defaultCurrency = ""

    //The Currency Unit taken from the exchange section of the API.
    var currencyUnit = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.gbp.unit
    var secondaryUnit = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.eur.unit
    var tertiaryUnit = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.usd.unit

    //Index of the dataObject
    var dataIndex = Int()

    //Objects
    let cryptoLabel = UILabel()
    let cryptoIconImage = UIImageView()
    let secondaryPriceLabel = UILabel()
    let mainPriceLabel = UILabel()
    let tertiaryPriceLabel = UILabel()

    //Custom Fonts.
    let customFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)
    let secondFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-BoldItalic" , size: UIFont.labelFontSize)

    //Setup Functions

    //Get the index of the dataObject
    func getIndex() {
        let index = CGPrices.shared.coinData.index(where: { $0.id == dataObject })!
        dataIndex = index
    }

    //Label
    func setupLabels() {

        //cryptoLabel from dataObject as name.
        cryptoLabel.text = CGPrices.shared.coinData[dataIndex].name

        //Prices from btc Exchange rate.

        let btcPrice = CGPrices.shared.coinData[dataIndex].current_price!
        let dcExchangeRate = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.gbp.value
        let secondaryExchangeRate = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.eur.value
        let tertiaryExchangeRate = CGExchange.shared.exchangeData[0].rates.usd.value

        let realPrice = (btcPrice * dcExchangeRate)
        let secondaryPrice = (btcPrice * secondaryExchangeRate)
        let tertiaryPrice = (btcPrice * tertiaryExchangeRate)

        secondaryPriceLabel.text = "\(secondaryUnit)\(String((round(1000 * secondaryPrice) / 1000)))"
        mainPriceLabel.text = "\(currencyUnit)\(String((round(1000 * realPrice)  /1000)))"
        tertiaryPriceLabel.text = "\(tertiaryUnit)\(String((round(1000 * tertiaryPrice) / 1000)))"
    }

    //Image
    func getIcon() {

        let chosenImage = CGPrices.shared.coinData[dataIndex].image
        let remoteImageUrl = URL(string: chosenImage)

        guard let url = remoteImageUrl else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cryptoIconImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

            }
            }.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //        for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
        //            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        //            print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
        //        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.setupLayout()
        self.getIndex()
        self.setupLabels()
        self.getIcon()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.dataLabel!.text = dataObject
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }

}
```

Edit: CGPrices Class with getData method:

```
import Foundation

class CGPrices {

    struct Coins: Decodable {
        let id: String
        let name: String
        let symbol: String
        let image: String
        let current_price: Double?
        let low_24h: Double?
        //let price_change_24h: Double?
    }

    var coinData = [Coins]()

    var defaultCurrency = ""
    var coins = Manager.shared.coins
    var coinsEncoded = ""

    static let shared = CGPrices()

    func encode() {
        for i in 0..<coins.count {
            coinsEncoded += coins[i]
            if (i + 1) < coins.count { coinsEncoded += "%2C" }
        }
        print("encoded")
    }

    func getData(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

        encode()

        let urlJSON = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=btc&ids=\(coinsEncoded)"

        guard let url = URL(string: urlJSON) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let coinsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coins].self, from: data)
                self.coinData = coinsData
                completion(arr)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("error serializing json: \(jsonErr)")
                print(data)
            }

            }.resume()

    }

    func refresh(completion: () -> ()) {
        defaultCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DefaultCurrency")!
        completion()
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you connect the segue to the button? If you want to invoke a segue through code, don't do that. Connect the segue between the source and destination view controller.

Comment: @DuncanC self.performsegue is called in the button, where and how would I put it so that the segue is performed when the button is pressed?

Comment: How did you create the segue? If you look at the segue in the storyboard, what is it connected to on both ends?

Comment: If you control-drag from a button to another storyboard, you can create a segue that gets triggered when you tap the button. That is **not** what you want, and a possible cause of your problem.

Comment: @DuncanC it is connected from the searchViewController, to the RootViewController(pageView)

Comment: Why do you segue from your search view controller to the root view controller? You should be either dismissing or popping to get back to the root view controller (depending on how you got there.) And how are you adding a page to your page view controller?

Comment: @DuncanC The searchViewController is inside a container view in the rootViewController, I used segue because previously I would just create a new page by bringing the searchView into view, pressing the button, which adds to the array that the ModelController uses to instantiate the DataViewControllers, but If i was currently on a page that was removed, it would crash, and if i added a page, it would cause problems when loading the new page for some reason.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be calling your own class CGPrices. It will confuse the shit out anyone with an iOS developing background as CG is usually a prefix for CoreGraphics, which is one of Apple's frameworks. Secondly I'd like to ask if you are sure that the completion handler is actually called after your asynchronous operation ended (sometimes I keep loosing track of the actual position for the callback in my functions)? Third: Why are you not checking if you actually successfully ran? Maybe it returns false and you don't get a result?

Comment: @Geru Sorry, I am new to any sort of coding and so was unaware of that. As far as I am concerned the completion handler functions correctly. debugging with print and removing the segue, everything works fine, the same function with completion is also called when the app loads, along with other api functions in a dispatch group, and the completions all work correctly. The error seems to be something to do with threads,  "CryptiX[376:33242] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIView init]", + giving me a green thread error on RVC:'let searchButton = UIButton()'

Comment: How do you initialize your view controllers? Usually they should be initialized on the main thread anyways. I suggest you to overwrite the two initializers and initialize your UIElements there. This should get rid of all issues regarding your main thread problem. Did you check the success flag? Could you share the getData method?

Comment: if you're using segues, I suppose you're using the storyboard. Why aren't you putting the ui elements into the storyboard and then just connecting them to your view controller via IBOutlets?

Comment: @Geru They are initialized by the model view controller and used by rootViewController, inside modelView controller: `let dataViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataViewController") as! DataViewController
        dataViewController.dataObject = self.pageData[index]
        return dataViewController`

Comment: @Geru I completed all the functions of my app while actively learning and I used storyboards. I found that they became cluttered and hard to manage, so I am rewriting the app from scratch and doing all of my objects, labels etc programatically, and using storyboard for the segues etc as being able to see it visually represented helps. If I remove the segue from the getData method, I get the DataViewController found nil error, as it did not update the list where the controller needs to get its data. so the getData seems to mean I instantiate RVCs from the background?

Comment: @Geru I updated the question with getData method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was inside my getData method I was not updated the coins array:

```
 var coinData = [Coins]()

var defaultCurrency = ""

var coins = Manager.shared.coins
var coinsEncoded = ""

static let shared = CGPrices()

func encode() {
    for i in 0..<coins.count {
        coinsEncoded += coins[i]
        if (i+1)<coins.count { coinsEncoded+="%2C" }
    }
    print("encoded")
}
```

I needed to add this line in getData:

```
func getData(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

//Adding this line to update the array so that the URL is appended correctly.
    coins = Manager.shared.coins

    encode()

let urlJSON = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=btc&ids=\(coinsEncoded)"
```

This would fix the finding nil in the DataViewController, but the app would still crash do to updating UI Elements on a background thread, as the segue was called inside the completion handler of the getData method. to fix this, I used DispatchQue.Main.Async on the segue inside the getData method in the addButton function, to ensure that everything is updated on the main thread, like so:

```
 @objc func addButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
    if Manager.shared.coins.contains(dataObject) {
        Duplicate()
    } else if Manager.shared.coins.count == 5 {
        max()
    } else {

        Manager.shared.addCoin(coin: dataObject)

            print("starting")

        CGPrices.shared.getData(arr: true) { (arr) in
            print("complete")
            print(CGPrices.shared.coinData)
//Here making sure it is updated on main thread.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCoin", sender: self)
            }

        }

    }
    searchBar.text = ""
}
```

Thanks for all the comments as they helped me to figure this out, and I learned a lot in doing so. Hopefully this can help someone else in their thought process when debugging, as one can get so caught up in one area of a problem, and forget to take a step back and look to other areas.